# Checking each line of data in a text file and identifying invalid data

Tags: java

so i've looked around and could'nt find anything specificaly related to what i'm wanting to accomplish, so i'm here to ask some of you folks if ya'll could help. I am a Uni student, and am struggling to wrap my head around a specfific task.

The task revolves around the following:

- Being able to have the program we develop check each line of data in a file we input, and report any errors (such as missing data) to the console via messages.

I am currently using Scanner to scan the file and .split to split the text at each hyphen that it finds and then placing that data into a String[] splitText array... the code for that is as follows:

```
File Fileobject = new File(importFile);
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(Fileobject);
while(fileReader.hasNext())
{
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    String[] splitText = line.split("-");
}
```

The text contained within the file we are scanning, is formatted as follows:

```
 Title - Author - Price - Publisher - ISBN
```

Title, Author and Publisher are varying lengths - and ISBN is 11characters, Price is to two decimal places. I am able to easily print Valid data to the console, though it's the whole validating and printing errors (such as: "The book title may be missing.") to the console which has my head twisted.

Would IF statements be suited to checking each line of data? And if so, how would those be structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the length/presence of each of the five columns, then consider the following:

```
while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    String line = fileReader.nextLine();
    String[] splitText = line.split("-");
    if (splitText.length < 5) {
        System.out.println("One or more columns is entirely missing.");
        continue;     // skip this line
    }
    if (splitText[0].length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Title is missing")
    }
    if (splitText[1].length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Author is missing")
    }
    boolean isValidPrice = true;
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(splitText[2]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        isValidPrice = false;
    }
    if (!isValidPrice) {
        System.out.println("Found an invalid price " + splitText[2] + " but expected a decimal.");
    }
    if (splitText[4].length != 11) {
        System.out.println("Found an invalid ISBN.");
    }
```

I do a two level validation above.  If splitting the current line on dash does not yield 5 terms, then we have missing columns and we do not attempt to even guess what data might actually be there.  If there are 5 expected columns, then we do a validation on each field by length and/or by expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your best bet is to use if statements (I can't think of another way?). For cleanliness, I recommend you create a validateData(String data) method, or multiple validator functions.

For example, because you know each line is going to be in the  Title - Author - Price - Publisher - ISBN format, you can write code like this:

```
public void validatePrice(String data) {
  //Write your logic to validate. 
}
public void validateAuthor(String data) {
  //Write your logic to validate. 
}
...
```

Then in your while loop you can call

```
validatePrice([splitText[0]);
validateAuthor([splitText[1]);
```

for each validator method.

Depending on your needs you can turn this more a bit more OOP style, but this is one cleanish way to do it.

Comment: With `validateTitle([splitText[0]);` how will you know `The book title may be missing` if the input in the file is `Author - Price - Publisher - ISBN`.

Comment: Could you show me an example of what the insides of the file you are trying to read is?


But the answer is it depends. In some cases, you could just check if the first string is empty. That would tell you there is no book title.

Comment: @RenegadeEagle Sure. A typical line of the file i am trying to read/validate is as follows:        “John Doe - John Doe - 29.00 - John Doe - John Doe”. All of the John Doe’s are Strings, and the price is a Double. Ofcourse John Doe isn’t the actual data, but it’s a representation of how it is laid out.

Comment: Right,

So in that case, split the string and check if each element is an empty string. Then you will know the information doesn't exist.
For example,
`
String testLine = "-Something-Test-Whatever";
  String[] split = testLine.split("-");
  System.out.println(split[0]);
`
This would return an empty string, giving you the missing book title.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to check for validation is that you have the proper number of entries (in this case check that the array is of size 5), and after that, you want to check each piece of data

If statements are a good way to go, and you can do something as simple as:

```
if(title.isBad()) print("error");
if(author.isBad()) print("error");
if(price.isBad()) print("error");
if(publisher.isBad()) print("error");
if(isbn.isBad()) print("error");
```

Replacing the .isBad with which ever clauses you are checking, such as string[i].isEmpty(), the length of the ISBN, etc.

For ones that take longer to check, such as the Price, you'll want to make some nested for loops, checking if it contains a period, contains only numbers, and on'y has 2 digits after the period.

Something helpful to know is the Wrapper classes for the primitive data types, if allows you to do

```
Character.isLetter(strings[i].charAt[j])
```

in the place of

```
(strings[i].charAt[j] >= 'A' && strings[i].charAt[j] <= 'Z') &&
(strings[i].charAt[j] >= 'a' && strings[i].charAt[j] <= 'z')
```

and

```
try{
    Double.parseDouble(strings[i]);
}
```

instead of manually checking the price.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This definitely seems like the best way to go. One question though, if one of the if statements is triggered as true and an error message fired will the program then stop scanning the file altogether? - if possible if that is the case i’d like to continue scanning the file until nothing is left to scan, and have it all then displayed into the console even if Title (for example) is missing (so the Title in the table, just displays as blank for that book etc.). Also, would a for loop be suitable for looping through and calculating things such as the total price for the amount of valid books?

Comment: the question i had above :) @Friedrich Kaiser

Comment: The program shouldn't stop for hitting a validation error unless that's what you tell it to do (via throwing an Exception and handling it by printing the stacktrace and exiting). It should continue on testing each entry, and then if you're looping through each line of the text file, it should keep going while `fileReader.hasNext()` returns true.

And yes, loop would be a viable method. But, if you wanted to be fancy and use some of the really good Java 8 API known as Streams, you could collect all your entries into a List and query them like you would a database, and sum all the prices.